# c, filling an array using dec2bin converter

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to convert a decimal to binary but I get unexpected result.

The following code returns `00000000000000000000000000000010ÔýDv`

Instead of `00000000000000000000000000000010`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *bin(long dec, long len);

main(){
    bin(2,32);
    return 0;
}

char *bin(long dec, long len){
    int c=0;
    char tmp[len],b[len];
    memset(tmp, '0', len);
    memset(b, '0', len);
    if(dec==0){c++;}
    while(dec>0){
        tmp[c++]=0x30+(dec%2);
        dec/=2;
    }
    while(c>0){b[len-c]=tmp[--c];}
    puts(b);
    return b;
}
```

Please help me out

Comment: You should not return pointers to local variables from functions, `b` in this case. If you do, you should not dereference them. If you do, you are not guaranteed to get any meaningful result because local variables cease to exist at the end of the functions where they're defined and their memory is reclaimed and likely reused for other variables and things. The usual result of reading and writing memory by dereferencing pointers to non-existent objects is reading garbage or corrupting something in the program's memory (e.g. another variable). I don't think you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `b` array is not 0-terminated. You are lucky that your program just doesn't crash!

`b` should be of length `len+1`, and when you are done writing in it, do `b[len] = 0;` before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

It simply is due to the fact that your `char b[32]` is exactly 32 chars long and you fill all 32 chars with either `'0'` or `'1'`. When it comes to `puts(b)` it expects a zero-terminated string as argument. Since there is not zero in your array it simply overflows and prints nonsense after your 32 digits.